# thymeleafで三項演算子を使った条件式を記述したい

Tags: thymeleaf

thymeleaf 三項演算子を使って条件式を書きたいです。

１、`prod.Num=='12'`の場合は'準備中'と出す。
２、`prod.Num=='13' && prod.sis=='春'`の場合は'出力'と出したいのですが、
どのように条件式を書いたらいいのか教えて頂きたいです。

```html
<div th:text="${prod.Num=='12' ? '準備中' : $ {prod.Num=='13' && prod.sis=='春'}? '出力' : '123'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

動作確認していないので間違っているかもしれませんが、おそらくこうだと思います。

```html
<div th:text="${prod.Num=='12'} ? '準備中' : ${prod.Num=='13' && prod.sis=='春'} ? '出力' : '123'"></div>
```

ただし、三項演算子をネストすると、可読性が下がるのでお勧めはしません。

**編集:**

`&&`ではなく`and`で、それから`()`が必要ですね。

```html
<div th:text="${prod.Num=='12'} ? '準備中' : (${prod.Num=='13' and prod.sis=='春'} ? '出力' : '123')"></div>
```

Comment: 有難うございますm(__)m　実行してみたのですが、There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)と出ました。

Comment: あー、`&&`ではなく`and`ですかね。あと`()`が必要かな。

Comment: 回答に追記しました。